# create permissions for web application module in wso2

Tags: wso2

I am using WSO2 application server to deploy my web application. There is User and Role management section in carbon products to manage roles and users in connected user store and use them for authorization purpose.

I want to create similar permission model for the access control of various modules in my web application deployed on WSO2. Also I want to assign these custom permissions to the role of connected userstore (where RDBMS or LDAP).

Please help me in this regard.

Thanks,

Harkomal

Answer (score 0):

You can use the existing permission model for this. If you check the "Users and Roles" menu, you will see the permissions attached to each role. You can create your own role, and assign permissions to that according to your need.  For the webapps, There are different level permissions are defined;

- Add
- configure etc..